# Check that the object has one property but not the other using toMatchObject in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Let's say something returns a complex object:

```
const value = {
    ...,
    client: { ... },
    ...
};
```

I want to test a bunch of properties, and for `client` I want to make sure that it has a certain `name`, but does not have `id` at all.

How do I implement it?

```
expect(value).toMatchObject({
   ...,
   client: ???,
   ...
});
```

If it was just `name` I would have done `client: { name: 'expected' }`.

I tried `client: { id: undefined, name: "expected" }`, but `undefined` is not the same as "does not have a property".

I know I can do a separate case of `expect(value).not.toHaveProperty('client.name')`, but it would be great to just have one `toMatchObject` (I need this in multiple tests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted with this, but still keen to know if there is a better way:

```
expect.extend({
    matchingAll(actual, expected) {
        return { pass: expected.every(e => e.asymmetricMatch(actual)) };
    }
});

expect(value).toMatchObject({
   ...,
   client: expect.matchingAll([
       expect.objectContaining({ name: 'expected' }),
       expect.not.objectContaining({ id: expect.anything() }),
   ]),
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

clear the property undefined and after to compare

```
function clear(a){
 Object.keys(a).forEach(key => {
  if (a[key] === undefined) {
    delete a[key];
  }
});
}
let client = { id: undefined, name: "expected" }
clear(client )
console.log(client)
```

Comment: That's other way around. In my case the `value` is something like `{ client: { name: 'expected' } }`, so there is already no `undefined`. I need a matcher that can match that, ensuring there is no `id`.